# Man gets his beat up car washed and it transforms into a space fighter

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

I remember seeing this as a young child, so mid to late 80's. This guy who works at a carwash gets a beat up crappy car but once it goes through the car wash it becomes a space fighter. He has to fend off what I remember as killer toupees (hair pieces). I just remember bits and pieces. And it's racking my brain.

Comment: And this was a live action movie or a cartoon or a tv show or a comic book or a novel or a short story or a stage play?

Answer (score 8):

You're probably thinking of a 1989 TV-movie called [The Rocket Boy](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0170513/). It definitely has a car that transforms into a spacecraft after going through a car wash, and some floating wigs. Hard to believe there'd be more than one film with both of those elements.

You can watch the film (or most of it) [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahMSCJTjzxw).

Comment: Thanks you have no idea how long I've been looking for this

Comment: Happy to help. Please upvote my answer and accept it by clicking on the check mark beside it.